# How can I Schedule the sales report on yearly...?

Tags: reporting, scheduled

I generate a yearly sales report that I want to schedule it to my manager yearly. But in salesforce schedule runs I found daily,weekly, monthly options. **Is there any option to schedule the report to my manager on yearly basis ?**

Comment: Sathya, I've taken the liberty to update your question tags. Please try to select tags related to the subject of your question, that both helps your question to be noticed by the right people, and it doesn't spam people following the tags you wrongly tag your question with.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke thanks for editing.by next time onwards i will select correct tag

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, a yearly schedule sounds pointless.

My suggestion: create a report folder: call it: Yearly reports. Save all the reports you want in that folder. Make sure to use the correct date filter.

Before the EOY or before the manager needs these reports, enter each of them (or have a DB that shows them all)